# Replace compiler when building Haskell project with Cabal

Tags: haskell, compiler-construction, compilation, cross-platform, cabal

Is it possible somehow to configure cabal project to use different compiler than GHC? Additional is it possible to control this by some flags?

I want to compile my project with GHC or [Haste](https://github.com/valderman/haste-compiler) (to JavaScript) based on some compilation flags.

It would be ideal if I could set my cabal configuration or my custom script to do something like:

```
-- target JS
cabal configure --target=js
cabal build

-- target Native
cabal configure --target=native
cabal build
```

Answer (score 5):

To build a Cabal project with either GHC or Haste, use the `cabal` binary for the former, and `haste-inst` (comes with haste) for the latter.

To have conditional code in in your modules, add `{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}` and use `#ifdef __HASTE__`, which will only be defined by haste, but not by GHC. Note that  `__GLASGOW_HASKELL__` is defined in both cases (which makes sense, as haste builds on GHC for large parts of the compilation). So you would use it like

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}

module Module where

compiler :: String
#ifdef __HASTE__
compiler = "haste"
#else
compiler = "GHC"
#endif
```

Theoretically, for conditional settings in the Cabal file something like this should work:

```
library
  exposed-modules:
        Module
  if impl(ghc)
        exposed-modules:
                Module.GHC
  if impl(haste)
        exposed-modules:
                Module.GHC
  build-depends:       base ==4.6.*
```

but it seems that even with `haste-inst`, `impl(ghc)` is true; [bug report](https://github.com/valderman/haste-compiler/issues/64) is filed.

Comment: Thank you! Can I use different `project.cabal` options also? In the code I can use `#ifdef` and I want for example the JS version not to have the `build-depends` of `graphviz`?

Comment: additional - does `{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}` is somehow connected with the `ghc cpp backend`? I want to use the `LLVM` backend.

Comment: @danilo2 To answer the second question: the CPP pragma doesn't have to do anything with C++. It allows one to use the [C preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) -- aka "cpp". The cpp only does conditional _preprocessing_ (including or excluding parts of code) using `#if` and `#ifdef`, but normally (in the case of Haskell) doesn't influence compilation itself.

Comment: @phg I understand I cannot create C preprocessor macros with this pragma?

Comment: My answer was partially incorrect, corrected that. @danilo2: For different Cabal options, see the linked bug report.

Answer (score 0):

While it's currently not possible to use `impl(haste)` in your cabal files, you can now check for `flag(haste-inst)` to see if your package is being built using `haste-inst`.